# Not being redirected to login

Tags: php, mysql, function

So i'm trying to make my login system to redirect a user that's not logged in.

```
<?php ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ?>


<?php require_once '/includes/config.php' ?>
<?php require_once '/includes/functions.php' ?>

<?php $user = new User(); ?>

<?php if (!($user -> LoggedIN())){
    header('login.php');
}
?>
```

But for some odd reason it's not doing that.
I'm also getting NULL When trying to dump

`$_SESSION['ID']`

My functions.php code here

```
<?php

class user
{
    function LoggedIN()
    {
        @session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['ID'])){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function realIP(){
    switch(true){
        case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
        case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        default : return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

//Kijkt of de gebruiker zijn account geblockeerd is
function isBanned($odb)
{
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
    $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($status == 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        //Blockeert de gebruiker, En logt hem uit
        session_destroy();
        return false;
    }
}

//Kijkt of de gebruiker admin is
function isadmin()
{
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` =  ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
    $rank = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($rank == 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


//de login functie (bewaart cookies en http header data door middel van @session_start();
?>
```

Comment: it's not redirecting, because you have output before the `header()` -> remove all those additional `?>     <?php`

Comment: Your user call should match the class name.

Comment: And add exit; after header function

Comment: `$_SESSION` will be empty because you never start the session with `session_start();`

Comment: It's matching the class name right?

http://prntscr.com/fjpq9w
But i'm getting other errors now.
http://prntscr.com/fjpouv

Comment: you've removed that line now: `$user = new User();` _BUT_ it should be `$user = new user();`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fjptc3

Nothing but a plain whitescreen now

http://prntscr.com/fjpu3o

Comment: remove the `@` before session_start in class. You're surpressing error messages there.

Comment: Removed, But does not show errors.

Comment: it should be `header('Location: login.php');`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a header type? If you want the user to get redirected you would want a Location header, like:

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

About `$_SESSION['ID']` returning `NULL`, could be anything. First of all, it is never set in the code you posted here. Second, you're ignoring error on `session_start()` (with the `@` prefix), why is this, was it returning an error?